# ¿Cómo puedo copiar datos de un archivo a otro con openpyxl?

Tags: python

No sé cómo puedo pasar datos de un archivo de excel a otro archivo donde ya viene diseñado con sus respectivos lugares.

Tengo este código pero no me sale nada, son sólo valores los que quiero copiar:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

ok1=load_workbook(r'\Desktop\proyecto OK\1.xlsx')
total=load_workbook(r'\Desktop\proyecto OK\Total Tie OK 2018 MACRO.xlsx')

ok1h=ok1.get_sheet_by_name('1')
totalh=total.get_sheet_by_name('Exi')


range1=ok1h['F2':'L28']
range2=totalh['C5':'I25']

range1 = range2

ok1.save('total.xlsx')
```

Comment: Hola Marco gracias por acomadar la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

[image: Recorte de archivo excel]

Teniendo dos archivos .xlsx, de nombres "origen" y "destino", el primero de ellos con la información de la imagen, el segundo, vacío.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

origen = load_workbook("origen.xlsx")
destino = load_workbook("destino.xlsx")

hoja_origen = origen.get_sheet_by_name('hoja')
hoja_destino = destino.get_sheet_by_name('hoja')

filas = hoja_origen["A1":"E5"]

for indice, fila in enumerate(filas):
  for celda in fila:
    hoja_destino[celda.column + str(indice+1)] = celda.value

destino.save('destino.xlsx')
```

El único cambio significativo con respecto de tú código es que, luego de obtener el rango, lo recorro en modo *fila-columna*, y de esta forma voy asignando en la variable correspondiente a la hoja del archivo de destino, el **value** de la celda actual:

> hoja_destino[celda.column + str(indice+1)] = celda.value

Comment: muchas gracias Rodrigo me ayudaste mucho con esa duda, te lo agradezco mil, soy nuevo también en el foro, no se si aquí pueda calificarte yo tu respuesta si es así házmelo saber y como para así hacerlo y gracias nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Intenté probar el funcionamiento de este código, pero me da el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo lo corregiste? He probado con otros tipos de variable y me salen errores diferentes.

Espero puedas ayudarme ¡Gracias!

Comment: esto no es una respuesta, edita tu pregunta

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/341624)